# XSL parse 2 xml file contemporary

Tags: xml, xslt

Can xsl parse to an XML file contemporary?

If so, how do I go about doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you mean by contemporary, but if you mean 'Can xsl parse 2 xml files simultaneously', the real answer is no, but it can use additional files through the 'document()' function.

Comment: Also, It should be say that XSLT is parser "agnostic". XSLT works on XML data model tree, regardless if this tree were built with parsed document, or by DOM or by any means.